# Factors with 3 digits

Tags: python

I am relatively new to python and I am having a go at the challenges on https://projecteuler.net. Currently, I am having trouble verifying that a number has two corresponding three-digit factors.

My idea is to take the nth number in a list of factors, and take the (len(list) - n)th factor (since these are the corresponding factors) and check that both of these have length 3 and it seems to work for many values. However, when I define another function that appends terms that meet this criteria to a new list, it comes out with a bunch of numbers that do not agree with this, with some not even having a single three digit factor.

An example of what I am looking for would be 10200, as it can be written as 102 x 100 (the product of two three digit integers). My function gives me the values that definitely are true but seems to throw in a lot of other values which are supposed to be false.

Here is what I used to find factors of a number:

```
def factors(x):
factors = []
count = 2
while count < x:
  if x % count == 0:
    factors.append(count)
  count = count + 1
return factors
```

Here is my function to find 2 multiples:

```
def two_multiples(y):
    count = 0
    while count < len(str(factors(y))) + 1:
      for g in factors(y):
        if len(str(factors(y)[count])) == 3 and len(str(factors(y)[len(factors(y))-count])) == 3:
          return True
        count = count + 1
      return False
```

Here is what I use to find values within lists:

```
def twofactorsthreedigits(numlist):
  twofactorsthreedigits = []
  for z in numlist:
    if two_multiples(z) == True:
    twofactorsthreedigits.append(z)
  return twofactorsthreedigits
```

When I print the result of twofactorsthreedigits(range(500)), a range within I should not get any values, I get

[202, 206, 214, 218, 226, 254, 262, 274, 278, 298, 302, 303, 309, 314, 321, 326, 327, 334, 339, 346, 358, 362, 381, 382, 386, 393, 394, 398, 404, 411, 412, 417, 422, 428, 436, 446, 447, 452, 453, 454, 458, 466, 471, 478, 482, 489]

Certainly to me it looks like I may have overcomplicated the functions but I cant spot where I have gone wrong. I think I have probably made a mistake with one of my while or for loops. I would be exceedingly grateful if anyone could point out any mistakes.

Comment: Could you point out which problem from projecteuler this is referring to? I am not sure I completely get the idea of what you are trying. Also, could you make your example code a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that would greatly help copying and running it on my machine

Comment: Add some sample input, what it should result in, and what you get now.

Comment: The problem I am working on is:
Problem 4 
A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.

Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

Comment: Are you sure you need to factor numbers to get your answer? Try going backwards.

Comment: Sure. When I print the result of twofactorsthreedigits(range(500)), a range within I should not get any numbers, I get [202, 206, 214, 218, 226, 254, 262, 274, 278, 298, 302, 303, 309, 314, 321, 326, 327, 334, 339, 346, 358, 362, 381, 382, 386, 393, 394, 398, 404, 411, 412, 417, 422, 428, 436, 446, 447, 452, 453, 454, 458, 466, 471, 478, 482, 489]. I am also unsure as to how I can change my code to an MWE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are really over complicating things.

Lets just do this the most basic way possible. Start with a nested loop with the largest values and decrement them. Check if their product is a palindrome and keep track of which palindrome is largest so far.

Example:

```
bestpalindrome = 0

def is_palindrome(n):
    return str(n)[::-1] == str(n)

for i in range(999, 100, -1):
    for j in range(999, 100, -1):
        temp = i*j
        if (is_palindrome(temp)):
            if temp > bestpalindrome:
                bestpalindrome = temp


print(bestpalindrome)
```

Comment: You can make this code much faster and there are a few tricks you can do to improve the code (hint think about how multiplying a number by 11 works), but hopefully this can get you started enough to come up with more optimal solution

Comment: Thank you! that definitely makes sense to me! It had just never occurred to me that I could do it this way. I was essentially finding the palindromes in a list, then making the reverse of that list, then finding the palindromes in that new list that fit the criteria and I just ended up with a bit of a mess as you can see. This is much nicer.